# How to split a number after n digits in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a number 2802 which is stored as a string in the backend. I want to split this number into 2 parts as 28 and 02 which should be shown as date 28/02? How can I do it with '/' in between them?

Comment: give some more example to better ans, what about '112','028' or something, is it always in 4 digit ?

Comment: `"2802".substring(0, 2) + "/" + "2802".substring(2);`

Comment: @Niklesh Simply I have a number as 2802 or 0103. I want / between 1st two and 2nd two numbers.

Comment: Are you asking about simple string manipulation? var str = "1234";var res = str.substr(0, 2)+"/"+str.substr(2,4);

Comment: is the size of string always 4?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes. It's size is always 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : you can use `substring` as shown below. `substring` used for getting string between start index and end index. In your case, get string from 0 to 1 and then 2 to 3.

```js
var str = "2802";
str = str.substring(0,2) + "/" + str.substring(2,4);
alert(str);
```

**[More information on Substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)**

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with regex

```js
var res = "2802".match(/\d{2}/g).join('/');

document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about simple string manipulation?

```
var str = "1234";
var res = str.substr(0, 2)+"/"+str.substr(2,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var str = "2802";

str = str.split('').map(function(el, i){
   if(i == 2){ el = '/'+el}
  return el;
});
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = str.join('');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

With regular expression:

```js
var str = "2802";

str = str.replace(/(.{1,2}$)/gi, '/$1');

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2802";
var output = [str.slice(0, 2), str.slice(2)].join('/');
```

Comment: i recommend `output = [str.slice(0, 2), str.slice(2)].join('/');`

Answer (score 0):

In this context conside 2802, 28 is date and 02 is month

Here **112**, **028** what is date and month ?

Comment: 1st two numbers are for date and 2nd two are for month. For 112 it is stored as 0112. For 028 stored as 0208 in the db.

Comment: Above you can see the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152258/how-to-split-a-number-after-n-digits-in-javascript/36152450?noredirect=1#answer-36153090

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution could be

```
var num = 2802;
var output = String(num).match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("/");
```

replace 2 with which ever number to split the number after n digits.

```
var n = 2;
var output = String(num).match(new RegExp('.{1,'+n+'}', 'g'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var db_date = '112';
var date_str = '';
if(db_date.slice(0,1)==0){
    var date_val = db_date.slice(0,2);
    var month_val = db_date.slice(2,3);

    if(month_val<=9){
        month_val = '0'+month_val;
    }
}else{
    var date_val = db_date.slice(0,1);
    date_val = parseInt(date_val);
    if(date_val<=9){
        date_val = date_val.toString();
        date_val = '0'+date_val;
    }
    var month_val = db_date.slice(1,3);
}
alert(date_val+'/'+month_val);
```